# Remotely run Regasm?

Tags: c#, com, regasm

I have a C# COM component that needs to be pushed out & registered to a remote computer. Does anyone know if this is possible via the Regasm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give psexec/pstools a try.  Here is a link:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Uses another process to remotely execute:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2187616.php

Or use a script as in this article:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20010819.asp